# How to split one line of text to multiple lines based on keyword/pattern?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer that contains what used to be multiple lines from a file, all merged together based on a pattern of larger lines for comparisons.  After changes have been made, I basically need to undo merging the lines together to re-write to a new StringBuffer to re-write the file as it originally was.

So for example, the file contains a line like this (all on one line):

```
'macro NDD89 Start;Load; shortDescription; macro(continued) stepone;steptwo,do stuff macro(continued) stepthree;more steps; do stuff macro(continued) finalstep'
```

I need that line to be re-written to multiple lines (split wherever there is the string "macro(continued)"):

```
macro NDD89 Start;Load; shortDescription;
macro(continued) stepone;steptwo,do stuff
macro(continued) stepthree;more steps; do stuff
macro(continued) finalstep'
```

If it helps, here is my code snippet that does the first part of taking the original file where it is in multiple lines and combines them to groups and writes to a new file:

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Buffer = new FileReader(C:/original.txt);
    BufferedReader User_File = new BufferedReader(Buffer);
    String Line_of_Text;
    while((Line_of_Text = User_File.readLine()) != null){
        if(Line_of_Text.startsWith("macro ")){
            sb.append("\n"+Line_of_Text);
        }else if(Line_of_Text.startsWith("macro(continued)")){
            sb.append(Line_of_Text);
        }else{
            sb.append(Line_of_Text+"\n");
        }
    }
    BufferedWriter OutFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/newFile.txt"));
    OutFile.write(sb.toString());
    OutFile.flush();
    OutFile.close();
```

I have been stuck on a way to do this for a while, any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution!

```
String x =oneLine.replace(" macro", "\nmacro");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the split() and contains() methods from String class can help you.

Ref: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a big String with no lines. You can test what you have above your line `if(Line_of_Text.startsWith("macro ")){` by inputting `System.out.println(Line_of_Text);`. That what you can see what is going wrong.

I'd change your appending code to:

```
String Line_of_Text = null;
while ((Line_of_Text = User_File.readLine()) != null) {
    Line_of_Text = User_File.readLine();
    String[] splitted = Line_of_Text.split("macro ");
    for (String part : splitted) {
        sb.append(part+"\n");
    }
}
```

This utilizes the `.split()` method to split your String into an array of String. You can use the items in that array to append them.

EDIT: I see you have multiple delimiters. `.split()` takes a regex delimiter, so you can try: `Line_of_Text.split("macro|macro\\(continued\\)");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#split` on a given token to split your `String`.

**Example**

```
String test = "'macro NDD89 Start;Load; shortDescription; macro(continued) stepone;steptwo,do stuff macro(continued) stepthree;more steps; do stuff macro(continued) finalstep'";
//                       // splits into String array, by
//                       //     | followed by...
//                       //     |  | literal text
//                       //     |  |   | double-escape on parenthesis, as
//                       //     |  |   | this is a regex pattern
String[] splitted = test.split("(?=macro\\(continued\\))");
System.out.println("Raw:\r\n");
// prints the raw array (hard to read, as inline)
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted)); 
// creates a list from the array and print each element one per line, trimmed
List<String> splittedList = Arrays.asList(splitted);
System.out.println("\r\nNice:\r\n");
for (String s: splittedList) {
    System.out.println(s.trim());
}
```

**Output**

```
Raw:

['macro NDD89 Start;Load; shortDescription; , macro(continued) stepone;steptwo,do stuff , macro(continued) stepthree;more steps; do stuff , macro(continued) finalstep']

Nice:

'macro NDD89 Start;Load; shortDescription;
macro(continued) stepone;steptwo,do stuff
macro(continued) stepthree;more steps; do stuff
macro(continued) finalstep'
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix to QuakCore's answer.

```
String breaker = "macro(continued)";
String x =oneLine.replace(" "+breaker, "\n"+breaker);
```